# Как сделать всплывающее окно с затемнением и размытием с помощью css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть кнопка по которой всплывает модальное окно. Как сделать так, чтобы на задний план за окном затемнялся и размыливался с помощью стилей?

```js
function toggle(el) {
  el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
}
```

```css
.application {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.application .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="order-call" onclick="toggle(hidden_content)">Заказать звонок</button>

<section class="application" id="hidden_content" style="display:none;">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Перезвоним вам через 5 минут!</h4>
    <a class="close" onclick="toggle(hidden_content)">X</a>
    <p>Заявка на выезд специалиста</p>;
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать подложку и `filter: blur(2px);`:

```js
function toggle(el) {
  el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
}
```

```css
.application {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.application .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.application:before {
   content: '';
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
   background: url(http://ultraimg.com/images/Ho6hQWs.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(2px);
}

.application:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="order-call" onclick="toggle(hidden_content)">Заказать звонок</button>

<section class="application" id="hidden_content" style="display:none;">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Перезвоним вам через 5 минут!</h4>
    <a class="close" onclick="toggle(hidden_content)">X</a>
    <p>Заявка на выезд специалиста</p>;
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: да, спасибо, с затемнением хорошо, а вот с размытием есть нюанс: если нужно размытие заднего плана контента при прокрутке страницы, то вариант с уже `background` не подойдет..

Comment: @Вася, http://codepen.io/ariona/pen/geFIK , http://codepen.io/ejsado/pen/kmrtp , http://codepen.io/jaeming/pen/EwsqC?editors=0110 , http://codepen.io/icebob/pen/LEbQVY

Comment: спасибо, подходит последний вариант и как я понимаю - без скриптов не обойтись. пробую делать по образцу, но у меня почему-то фон с дорогой не затемняется..
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqNKEg

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен еще один блок `overlay`, который будет всплывать под окном, и вот с ним уже работать.

```js
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

function toggle(el) {
  el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
  overlay.style.display = (overlay.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
}
```

```css
.application {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
}
.application .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
.overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="order-call" onclick="toggle(hidden_content)">Заказать звонок</button>

<section class="application" id="hidden_content" style="display:none;">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Перезвоним вам через 5 минут!</h4>
    <a class="close" onclick="toggle(hidden_content)">X</a>
    <p>Заявка на выезд специалиста</p>;
  </div>
</section>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
```